# How to delete x days older file from a Folder with specified extension

Tags: vbscript

Here is the VBS code I have, which is deleting all the .exe or any other given extension files from a folder of a given day of old files.

But it's asking for confirmation before deleting each file, which I have to then confirm manually by clicking OK. I need to disable that confirmation, so that the script deletes all the specified extension files once I clicked, and no confirmations are needed.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim strExtensionsToDelete,strFolder
Dim objFSO, MaxAge, IncludeSubFolders

' Folder to delete files
strFolder = "C:\Users\Public\Downloads"
' Delete files from sub-folders?
includeSubfolders = True
' A comma separated list of file extensions
' Files with extensions provided in the list below will be deleted
strExtensionsToDelete = "exe,.exe"
' Max File Age (in Days).  Files older than this will be deleted.
maxAge = 5

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

DeleteFiles strFolder, strExtensionsToDelete, maxAge, includeSubFolders

Sub DeleteFiles(ByVal strDirectory, ByVal strExtensionsToDelete, ByVal maxAge, includeSubFolders)
    Dim objFolder, objSubFolder, objFile
    Dim strExt

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        For Each strExt In Split(UCase(strExtensionsToDelete), ",")
            If Right(UCase(objFile.Path), Len(strExt)+1) = "." & strExt Then
                If objFile.DateLastModified < (Now - MaxAge) Then
                    WScript.Echo "Deleting:" & objFile.Path & " | " & objFile.DateLastModified 
                    objFile.Delete
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    If includeSubFolders = True Then ' Recursive delete
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
            DeleteFiles objSubFolder.Path, strExtensionsToDelete, maxAge, includeSubFolders
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `WScript.Echo` line, or simply run the script with `cscript.exe` instead of `wscript.exe`.

Comment: removed all the lines starting "wscript.echo"
and it's working perfectly

Thanks!